# Getting error when inserting row in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm new to MongoDB. I want to create a collection and insert a document in the collection.

I have created a database and also created a collection but I am getting an error when an interesting document in the collection.

Below my code

```
db.createCollection("students", {
    validator: {
      $jsonSchema: {
         bsonType: "object",
         required: [ "name", "year", "major", "gpa", "address.city", "address.street" ],
         properties: {
            name: {
               bsonType: "string",
               description: "must be a string and is required"
            },
            gender: {
               bsonType: "string",
               description: "must be a string and is not required"
            },
            year: {
               bsonType: "int",
               minimum: 2017,
               maximum: 3017,
               exclusiveMaximum: false,
               description: "must be an integer in [ 2017, 3017 ] and is required"
            },
            major: {
               enum: [ "Math", "English", "Computer Science", "History", null ],
               description: "can only be one of the enum values and is required"
            },
            gpa: {
               bsonType: [ "double" ],
               minimum: 0,
               description: "must be a double and is required"
            },
            "address.city" : {
               bsonType: "string",
               description: "must be a string and is required"
            },
            "address.street" : {
               bsonType: "string",
               description: "must be a string and is required"
            }
         }
      }
   }
})
```

Insert record in Collection

```
db.students.insert({
    name: "Pramod Kushwaha",
    gender:"Male",  
    year: NumberInt(2018),  
    major: "Math",
    gpa: NumberDecimal(3.22),
    address: {
      city: "NYC",
      street: "Narol"
    }
})
```

Getting Error

```
WriteResult({
    "nInserted" : 0,
    "writeError" : {
        "code" : 121,
        "errmsg" : "Document failed validation"
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I got an answer

```
db.students.insert({
    name: "Pramod Kushwaha",
    gender:"Male",  
    year: NumberInt(2018),  
    major: "Math",
    gpa: 3.22,
    address: {
      city: "NYC",
      street: "Narol"
    }
})
```

In the above insert, Query has datatype issue in `gpa` field. I have changed `NumberDecimal(3.22)` to `3.22` as double datatype values.